# YARN nodemanager error while running basic sparkpi example

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am running a basic spark program to test my YARN setup with Spark. I am running a job similar to the example one on the website.

```
 spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 75 -- 
 executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 6g --class 
org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi  
 /home/spark/examples/jars/spark_examples.jar 1000
```

However, the job never terminates and the nodemanagers on the different nodes show this error:

`2020-03-16 14:27:42,917 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: couldn't find container container_1584386586744_0001_01_000319 while processing FINISH_CONTAINERS event`

I am not sure whats causing this. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is the yarn-site.xml file for the standalone cluster(causes error):

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
 <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
 <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>0</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>172.16.1.1</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>10.66.4.100:8088</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>172.16.1.1</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>262144</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>262144</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>56</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>56</value>
</property>
```

Here is the yarn-site.xml file for the EMR cluster(which works)

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.timeline-service.hostname</name>
<value>ip-172-31-63-120.ec2.internal</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.web-proxy.address</name>
<value>ip-172-31-63-120.ec2.internal:20888</value>
</property> 

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>ip-172-31-63-120.ec2.internal:8025</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>ip-172-31-63-120.ec2.internal:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>ip-172-31-63-120.ec2.internal:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
<value>http://ip-172-31-63-120.ec2.internal:19888/jobhistory/logs</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.dispatcher.exit-on-error</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
 <value>/mnt/yarn,/mnt1/yarn</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>

<property>
<description>Where to store container logs.</description>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
<value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers</value>
</property>

<property>
<description>Where to aggregate logs to.</description>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
<value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
</property>


<property>
 <description>Classpath for typical applications.</description>
 <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
 <value>
    $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
    $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
    $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
    $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
    $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*,
    /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*,
    /usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf,
    /usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*,
    /usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*,
    /usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*,
    /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar,
    /usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-hadoop-goodies.jar,
    /usr/lib/spark/yarn/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo.jar,
    /usr/lib/spark/yarn/lib/datanucleus-core.jar,
    /usr/lib/spark/yarn/lib/datanucleus-rdbms.jar,
    /usr/share/aws/emr/cloudwatch-sink/lib/*,
    /usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*
 </value>
 </property>

<!-- The defaut setting (2.1) is silly. The virtual memory is not 
   a limiting factor on 64Bit systems, at least not a limiting  
    resource, so make it large, very large. -->
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
<value>5</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.node-labels.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression</name>
<value>CORE</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.node-labels.fs-store.root-dir</name>
<value>file:///mnt/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/nodelabels</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.node-labels.configuration-type</name>
<value>distributed</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation.enable-local-cleanup</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
<value>${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:8041</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.container-metrics.enable</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.recovery.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.recovery.supervised</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path</name>
<value>/emr/instance-controller/lib/yarn.nodes.exclude.xml</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.cross-origin.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
<value>32</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-ms</name>
<value>250</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.node-labels.provider</name>
<value>config</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.node-labels.provider.configured-node-partition</name>
<value>CORE</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.timeline-service.http-cross-origin.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count</name>
<value>64</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
<value>4</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.client.thread-count</name>
<value>64</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.container-manager.thread-count</name>
<value>64</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count</name>
<value>64</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>12288</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.client.thread-count</name>
<value>20</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
<value>172800</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.fetch.thread-count</name>
<value>20</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>12288</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>128</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>172.31.63.120</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>32</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.timeline-service.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Am I missing any YARN configurations in the xml file?

Comment: Why do you have 172.16 and 10.66 network addresses?

Comment: The ip addresses for my head/master node is 172.16.1.1, and the workers are 172.16.1.2, etc. the 10.66 network address is a private ip that i can use on the local host to view the status of YARN processes on the webapp.

Comment: Is there a standard setup that I am missing for this?

Comment: I find it strange that you have two local networks. Typically, 172.16 is a docker network, in which case you should never use ip addresses plus Hadoop wasn't really design with docker in mind... Do you need Hadoop? For example, Minio recently broke HDFS processing benchmarking

Comment: I need hadoop for the HDFS file system, and the ip for my nodes are as given in my previous post. I'd rather not move towards using new software at the moment. After running the same program on an EMR cluster, the program ran succesfully. I have edited my post with the other yarn-site.xml file for the EMR cluster.

Comment: If you're using EMR, then data is stored in S3 and only copied to a local, temporary HDFS. That saves on costs. If you want to use S3 outside of AWS, then MinIO is exactly what you'd want. Please upload the file as text, not an image. And which server are you pulling these files from? Each node has its own copy, so maybe one of them is wrong

Comment: The cluster which this error is on is a standalone cluster in a datacenter, but I used an EMR cluster as an example. I would rather stick with using HDFS rather than MinIO. The issue must be with the yarn configurations, because I set up both clusters identically except for the yarn files. I am confused what you mean when you say "what server are you pulling these files from" - they are both configurations files for hadoop.

Comment: Hadoop is a distributed filesystem, not often a single server. If you have two node managers, each has their own copy of these XML files. If they differ, you get issues.... Besides, you've still not really answered my networking question about the different subnets. Typically YARN and HDFS are in the same one. Are you able to SSH and ping between them? Telnet the HDFS and YARN ports? Again, I'm not able to see the images that are uploaded to posts

Comment: All the node managers have the same copy of these XML files(I have made sure of this).  I am pulling this version from the head/master node(which is also the namenode for hadoop). I am able to ssh and ping between them. I also will reupload the image as a file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209895/discussion-between-superwiz1-and-cricket-007).

Comment: I honestly don't know what more than 10 of these properties actually do. I typically use Ambari for my cluster installations and it automatically fills in all these... But I think you'll be able to find something more useful in the Spark UI. Plus that log is only a warning, not an error

Comment: The application never completes on the web address platform, and this is the only error-like message printed out in the logs, which is why I posted it. Should I install ambari and retry? On the Spark UI, it shows memory and cores being allocated but no actual progress is made by the partitions in calculating pi.

Comment: I strongly encourage it. https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/handcranking-of-hadoop-clusters-using-config-management-tools Another thing to consider is that you really don't need 75 executors, each with 6g of memory only to calculate a simple number... Do you really have 450G of memory and 150 cores on your standalone cluster?

Comment: I have 120 cores and around 300G of memory on the standalone cluster. I shall install ambari and retry the configurations.